# Is it possible to scroll to a treeviewitem that's not visible when a treeview is virtualized?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been trying to get it to scroll when the treeview is virtualized. I have succeeded when it is not virtualized, but it takes the treeview far too long to load.

*Q: Is it possible to do? And how would I go about it?*

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to change the way you work with `TreeView`s. Use data binding to control selection and expansion. This way WPF will do all the work for you.

- Create a view model for each tree node, and add the `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` properties
- Use the `ItemContainerStyle` to bind the `TreeViewItem`s to it:

  ```
      <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
              <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                      Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
              <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                      Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          </Style>
      </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  ```
- Now you can write code that manipulates the *data of the tree*, the binding will do the rest.

Here's an example of a generic `Node<T>` view model and a recursive method that searches for the first node that matches a value, expanding and selecting nodes along the way:

```
    class Node<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged // should implement this properly on all properties for binding to work
    {
        public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        public T Value { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Node<T>> Children { get; }
    }

    bool TryFindNode<T>(Node<T> node, T value)
    {
        bool wasFound = false;

        if (Equals(node.Value, value))
        {
            node.IsExpanded = true;
            node.IsSelected = true;
            wasFound = true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var childNode in node.Children)
            {
                if (SearchNode(childNode, searchText))
                {
                    node.IsExpanded = true;
                    wasFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return wasFound;
    }
```